# Windows Phone Toolkit AutoCompleteBox binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

I need to bind data to the dropdown options of the AutoCompleteBox control in the Windows Phone Toolkit.

This is the class. I create an array of the objects of this class and the autocompletebox's itemsource is this array of this class -

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I was able to show the "Name" in the dropdown list of the autocompletebox, but here is the problem-

When I select a value ("Name") from the dropdown list, the text of the autocompletebox changes to something like -

```
"Classes.MyClass"
```

Instead of the value I selected, for example - I select "Jhon", in he selection changed event of the dropdown list I get the selected Object and I can get the "Name" property from it. but I need the text in the autocomplete box to be "Jhon". how to do that??

EDIT:-

Here is the xaml

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="SearchText" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="LightGray" Foreground="Gray" FilterMode="None" MinimumPrefixLength="0" KeyDown="SearchText_KeyDown" TextChanged="ACBSearchText_TextChanged" Loaded="SearchText_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ACBSearchText_SelectionChanged">
                    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan Added my xaml.

Comment: @Sajeetharan also On keyDown event, the autocompletebox does not register the enter key as a keystroke??

Comment: Did that work? can you mark it as an answer!You need to use KeyUP event on enter key

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thank You buddy! You are most helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the [`ValueMemberBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox.valuememberbinding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in your AutoCompleteBox

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="SearchText" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: Whenever I use the selectionchanged event, it is called twice?? I cannot understand why, I even created a dummy test application(with just a list of strings) that also has a bug - when I select an item, it is selected, but when I press the backspace key it fires an exception??